# Close div when other div link is clicked jquery

Tags: jquery

Need some help closing an expanding `div` when a link to open another expanding `div` is clicked.

I've tried using examples from other functions but I don't have a good enough understanding to alter it to work.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="service" id="service-box1">
    <a class="learn-more" id="show1" data-href="service1">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="service" id="service-box2">
    <a class="learn-more" id="show2" data-href="service2">Learn More</a>
</div>
<div class="service-content" id="service1">
    <p>Title</p>
</div>
<div class="service-content" id="service2">
    <p>Title</p>
</div>
```

Here's the function:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show1').click(function() {
        var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
        $('#serivce1').not($div).hide();
        $div.slideToggle();
    });
});

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#show2').click(function() {
        var $div = $('#' + $(this).data('href'));
        $('#serivce2').not($div).hide();
        $div.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

So if the `#show1` button is clicked and displays the `#service1` `div` then the `#show2` button is clicked, the `#service1` `div` should close and open the `#service2` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use onclick function.

**HTML**

```
<div class="service" id="service-box1">
    <a class="learn-more" id="show1" data-href="service1" onclick="showservice1()">Learn More</a>
</div>

<div class="service" id="service-box2">
    <a class="learn-more" id="show2" data-href="service2" onclick="showservice2()">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY/JS**

```
function showservice1() {
    $('#service1').show(100);
    $('#service2').hide(100);
}

function showservice2() {
    $('#service1').show(100);
    $('#service2').hide(100);
}
```

And 1 more thing...

I saw you **TYPO** where you declare ID as "service1" and "service2" but in jquery you call "serivce1" and "serivce2". That's why it wont work

Hopefully this help you